# Convert TimeStamp to Teradata TimeStamp

Tags: teradata

I have a table which contains DateTime in the following format
'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI'
now I am trying to convert this time into Teradata Timestamp but getting an error.

What I have tried is:

select cast('4/13/2022 0:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0) Format 'mm/dd/yyyyBhh:mi')

but it return invalid timestamp error.
Any method for this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You've got single digit month and hour values in there. I don't think there's any way to make Teradata play nice with those, other than adding the leading 0s.

I think this should work but you'll want to test it thoroughly.

```
select cast (regexp_replace('4/13/2022 0:00', '\b([0-9])\b', '0\1') AS TIMESTAMP(0) Format 'mm/dd/yyyyBhh:mi')
```

Answer (score 0):

after different solutions, this worked.

```
    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH( STRTOK(ACT_TIME, '/', 1)) = 1 THEN TO_TIMESTAMP( '0' || ACT_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') END ACT_TIME_TIMESTAMP
   ,CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH( STRTOK(ACT_TIME, '/', 1)) = 1 THEN CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP( '0' || ACT_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS DATE) END ACT_TIME_DATE
   ,CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH( STRTOK(ACT_TIME, '/', 1)) = 1 THEN CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP( '0' || ACT_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIME) END ACT_TIME_DATE
```